# A simple list of objects to display and edit with Angular

Tags: javascript, angular.js, crud

I want to create a simple CRUD app using angular on the frontend.

I'm not really happy with the logic here, it seems a bit convoluted for fairly simple functionality.

```
    <div class = "container-fluid">
        <div id = "table" class = "row" ng-repeat = "o in objects" ng-init = "o.isBeingEdit = false">
            <div class ="col-xs-1"> {{o.objectId}}</div>
            <input type = "text" ng-model = "o.someContent" class = "col-xs-9" ng-disabled = "!o.isBeingEdit"/> 
            <input type = "button" class = "col-xs-2 btn btn-default" ng-click = "editSave(o)" ng-value = "o.isBeingEdit? 'Save' : 'Edit'"/>
        </div>      
    </div>
```

‌

```
$scope.editSave = function(o){
    if (o.isBeingEdit){
        //Save
        BackendService.updateObject(o).then(function(data){
            o.isBeingEdit = false; 
        }, function(data){
            o.isBeingEdit = false;
            handleServerError(data);
        }); 
    }
    else{
        o.isBeingEdit = true;
    }
};
```

Is there a much much much nicer way of doing this?